# Print all records form continious form Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a continious form in Access containing a recordset that can be filtered from within the form. See image below:

[image: Continious form access]

I would like to be able to print all the selected records. Exporting the selected records to a report or printing the records directly are both fine for me. I have been searching everywhere but all posts are about printing single records.

The filter is added to the form making a filter string that updates when one of the filter fields on the form is changed.

```
If txtDatumvan <> "" Then
    strFilter = " Clng(format(s.Begin_DatumTijd, 'yyyymmdd')) >= " & CLng(Format(Me.txtDatumvan, "yyyymmdd")) & " "

    If txtDatumTot <> "" Then
        strFilter = strFilter + " AND Clng(format(s.Begin_DatumTijd, 'yyyymmdd')) <= " & CLng(Format(Me.txtDatumTot, "yyyymmdd")) & ""
    End If
```

Thanks in advance,

FIXED: I loaded the records into a report instead of printing the form directly. I did this using a filter string which is filled by the input of the textboxes on top of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print all records on the current object to the default printer for that object, you can use the following VBA:

```
DoCmd.PrintOut acPrintAll
```

Continuous forms are clumsy for printing, though. I recommend you use a report. If you want me to show you how to transfer filters from a form to a report, you need to be specific about how you're adding those filters.

Comment: I've added the filter part to the question

Comment: That doesn't include the code actually applying the filter